# Friend request send only one time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is my code of friend request accept and reject but one user send many times request same user.it is not rights...how can i done perfect work? This is my code.
You can see problem in database.
[image]
How can i separate 2 API

1. Send friend request
2. Accept/reject request.

```html
  public function request(Request $request) {
    $input =$request->all();

    $user = User::find($request->user_id_1);

    if(empty($user)){
        return [
            'status' => 'error',
            'msg' => 'no user found'
        ];
    


    if($request->approved == "yes"){
        $friend = new Friend();
        $friend->user_id_1 = $user->id;
        $friend->user_id_2 = Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;
        $friend->approved = "yes";

        $friend->save();            
        $data = array("status" => $user);
        return $data;
    }
    else{
        $friend->approved = false;
        $friend->save();
        return [
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'true' => true
        ];
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this.

```
$request = 'Your request db model'::where([['user_id_1' => $request->user_id_1],['user_id_2' => $request->user_id_2]])
            ->orWhere([['user_id_1' => $request->user_id_2],['user_id_2' => $request->user_id_1]])->get();

        if($request != null){
            //say user you already sent a request.
        }
```

tell me if this worked.good luck.

Comment: @RuhithUdakara don't post multiple answers to the same question. Edit and update your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

are you sending `user_id_1` and `user_id_2` in the same `request` payload? If so,before save the `request` in db check `user_id_1,user_id_2` and the approved status in the database and vise versa. If any record exists in the database you can give the `error` message to the user.

Hope this help.

Comment: How can i do that? -@Ruhith Udakara